# Modeling with equations riddle

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A father said that sevens years ago, he was eleven times as old as his daughter. Now he is four times as old as she is. How old is the father?

Can this be solved as a system of equations? I am stuck with this problem because I don't think that I am properly setting up the model.
$$FathersAge - 7 = 11daughtersage$$
$$4daughtersage=Fathersage$$

Comment: seven years ago daughter was also 7 years younger, so subtract 7 from daughter's current age $(F-7)=11(D-7)$, the second equation is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ = father's age now, and $y$ = daughter's age now. Then:

$x-7=11(y-7)$, and

$x=4y$.

From this we have: $4y-7=11y - 77 \to y = 10$. Thus: $x = 4(10) = 40$.

Dad is $40$ years old now.

Comment: Small note: its better to show the method passed the part that they need, and then let them finish it. The equations are fine though

Comment: How did you get $$4y-7$$

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: $x - 7 = 4y - 7$

Answer (score 2):

Fathers age = F

Daughters age= D

Seven years ago, he was 11 times as old as his daughter

$(F-7)=11(D-7)$

Now he is four times as old

$F=4D$

You forgot the $-7$ to the daughter in the first equation